# Jordan Canonical Form of complicated Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, canonical-transformation

$$B:=        \left[ \begin{matrix}
        -1 & 9 &0 &0 &0 \\
        0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0&3&-1&0&0 \\         0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0&-2&-2&0&1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right]$$
 How do I find the Jordan Canonical Form of $B$? Also, I was wondering if there was any way to compute a formula for $B^n$ far all integers $n\geq5$? Or if thats not possible here?

Comment: For computing the Jordan Canonical Form, there is a standard, algorithmic approach. Once you've got this form though, you can express the matrix as $B = SJS^{-1}$ where J denotes the form. Exponentiating is easy, as the inside copies of $S$ and $S^{-1}$ will cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

Find the eigenvalues first. There are two different eigenvalues: $\lambda=-1$ with algebraic multiplicity 3, and $ \lambda=1$ with algebraic multiplicity 2.
When $\lambda=-1$, two eigenvectors can be found (aka geometric multiplicity=2) using $A-\lambda I=0$. Notice the algebraic multiplicity (3) exceeds geometric multiplicty (2) by 1 for this eigenvalue. 
When $\lambda=1$, two eigenvectors can be found (aka geometric multiplicity=2) using $A-\lambda I=0$.
Thus the Jordan Canonical Form of B is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Make sure to double check the calculations.

Comment: this is great. How'd you find the determinate of the 5x5  matrix with the diagonals having the eigenvalues though? I'm stuck at that part

Comment: @user316861 Do you mean the determinant of your initial matrix $B$?